# Create a geo_point from two different fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have two separate fields for latitude and longitude inside a model. How can we create a mapping to create a geo_point type from it in ElasticSearch?

Comment: you will need an ingest pipeline to bring the two fields into one of the accepted formats for geo_point fields

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new field with type [geo_point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geopoints.html)

mapping

```
{
    "pin" : {
        "properties" : {
            "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can populate the field at index time using any of the input formats described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_input_structure)

For eg.

```
{
    "pin" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 41.12,
            "lon" : -71.34
        }
    }
}
```